# how to connect remote server wordpress mysql via python

Tags: mysql, python

I am very new to mysql. 
I made server from amazon lightsail, linux wordpress instance. 
I know how to connect localhost mysql, so I tried same way.

```
import pymysql
connetion = pymysql.connect(host='xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
                         port = 80
                         user='userid',
                         password='userpw',
                         db='bitnami_wordpress',
                         charset='utf8',)
c =connetion.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT * FROM 'wp_db7_forms'")
result = c.fetchall()
print(result)
```

for host, tried my server public IP, localhost:3306(written in wp-copfig.php),

for port, tried 80 , 8080, 3306

for user and password, tried user, password from wp-config.php and my id and pw from phpmyadmin(which set host as *)

but what I only get is this error

```
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')
```

wp_db7_froms have only one row, so I don't think error occur because of data amount.

I even tried `from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder` but not worked

how can I connect to remote server wordpress mysql? 
I just need to read db table.

because my app need to check db before work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect from some visual tool like MySQL Workbench, use parameters that lightsail provided to you. Also this tutorial might help https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-connecting-to-your-mysql-database. After success connection you will understand what parameters should be used in pymysql.connect.